# How to catch what is POST'ed to rest api

Tags: spring, rest, api

I have a rest api set up at api/books, and one can send a new book object there, and it will be added to the database. The guestion is, how can I correctly catch what is being POST'ed, so one can for example, validate what is being sent?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/books", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String bookSavePost(@RequestBody Book book) {
    bookRepository.save(book);
    return "redirect:/api/books";
}
```

This works, as in it saves the book and I can catch what the user sends, but with this enabled, it overrides the default REST method, which doesn't allow one to actually view the api anymore. If I change this particular method to GET, it returns a string "redirect:/api/books", so it doesn't even redirect anything. Is there some way to actually redirect it to the rest api endpoint?

Comment: Could you try `@PostMapping("/api/books")`

Comment: As in replace RequestMapping with PostMapping? That didn't work. Isn't PostMapping just a shortcut for @RequestMapping(value="/api/books", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: yes, but it also sets @RequestMapping(value="/api/books", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumers = "application/json", produces=  "application/json"). I thougth that the absent of `consumers` property was your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own reuquest Interceptor .

Spring provides HandlerInterceptor class :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Here is a quick sample how to do this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: I didn't have to do this after all (this was just a crappy school project that I don't want to get involved too deeply with), but it can be done with this.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect requires three two things to be successful: A HTTP code of 301 or 302 AND a `location` header that includes the endpoint to which you want the client to visit.

E.g., in the headers section you should have

`location: '/correct/endpoint'`

Comment: Well, this still means that I'll get 'GET is not supported' as it will just redirect itself to the GET method again - and calling the POST requires that you have something that matches @RequestBody Book book.

This is what I did:
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
  response.setHeader("Location", "/api/books");

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question. Are you saying you're trying to force a POST when the user sends a GET to that endpoint?

Comment: I'm just trying whatever to get this working, sending a POST request from GET method could be one thing. It's just that I don't know how rest api works in the first place, it seems to just magically run in the background. I would just like to catch what is being POST'ed to rest api.

Comment: I think the problem is partially that when you define a custom method, it just overwrites the whatever black magic that's in rest api. Redirecting causes it to just redirect to the same newly-defined method over and over again..

Comment: @ivaylo I want it to redirect to the same api, but just do some things with what is being POST'ed.